# Structure of the group of arithmetic functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, abelian-groups

This question was originally posted in [Elements of finite order in the group of arithmetic functions under Dirichlet convolution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265446/elements-of-finite-order-in-the-group-of-arithmetic-functions-under-dirichlet-co/266702#comment582643_266702)

and it goes as follows: Let G be the group consisting of all arithmetic functions (i.e. functions $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$) under the "convolution"operation  $\ast,$  defined as $$(f\ast g)(n):=\sum_{ab=n}f(a)g(b), n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
(Note that each function in the group assigns the value $1$ to $1.$)

Alexander Gruber showed in the aforementioned post that G is a torsion-free abelian group. A few further facts can be easily proved:

(1) G is not finitely generated and in particular is infinite.

(2)If one lets H to denote the subgroup of G consisted of multiplicative functions, then $|G:H|=\infty.$

However my question is: What is known in the literature about the group structure of G ?

Comment: $f(1) = 1$ isn't part of the definition of an arithmetic function; please include this condition explicitly in the definition of $G$ (or else it isn't a group).

Comment: Only when f(1) Not Equal 0 the function has an inverse. ( See: T. Apostol IANT 2.7 )

Answer (score 7):

$G$ is a certain subgroup of the multiplicative group of the *ring* of all arithmetic functions under convolution and pointwise addition. This ring is isomorphic to the ring of formal [Dirichlet series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series), which is in turn isomorphic to the ring of formal power series $\mathbb{C}[[x_1, x_2, ... ]]$ in countably many variables, one for each prime (write out $\frac{1}{n^s}$ in terms of the prime factorization of $n$).

So the question reduces to the following: what is the structure of the group of complex power series in countably many variables with constant term $1$ under multiplication?

To answer that question, observe that the logarithm of such a formal power series is well-defined using the formal power series of $\log (1 + x)$, and the result is a formal power series with constant term $0$, and conversely. Hence the group in question is isomorphic to the additive group of formal power series in countably many variables with constant term $0$, which is just a countable product of copies of $\mathbb{C}$, or in purely group-theoretic terms a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ of dimension the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: "purely group-theoretic terms"?

Comment: @Stefanos: "countable product of copies of $\mathbb{C}$" describes a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, but the OP is only interested in the group structure. (Maybe you're confused about "vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$"? This is a property, not a structure.)

Comment: I don't think I am confused. I'm only observing that "pure group theory" and "vector spaces" don't mix.

Comment: @Stefanos: sure they do. First of all, vector spaces are groups. Second of all, "vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$" is a group-theoretic condition on an abelian group. It means that the group is not only divisible but that it is a coproduct of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$. In particular, specifying the action of $\mathbb{Q}$ is not additional data; if such an action exists, it is unique.

Comment: I am sorry, but vector spaces are not groups.

Comment: @Stefanos: er... then I think you _are_ confused. Vector spaces are precisely abelian groups together with the action of a field.

Comment: This "together" part is precisely why a different term is needed. Vector spaces are structures with two operations, whereas groups have only one.

Comment: @Stefanos: okay, but do you understand what I mean when I say that "vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$" is a group-theoretic condition? It is _not a new structure._

Comment: Yes, you elaborated on this point in your second comment. My beef was the phrasing you used. Just doing my bit to keep group theory pure I guess.

Comment: @Stefanos: how would _you_ phrase it? "Coproduct of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$" assumes the axiom of choice; what would you do in the absence of choice?

Answer (score 2):

Your definition must include that $f(1)\not= 0$, because $f^{-1}(n)$ is recursively defined in terms of $1/f(1)$.  (The formula can be found on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution#Dirichlet_inverse).)  So, denote by $\mathcal{A}$ the group of all arithmetic functions with $f(1)\not= 0$.

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be the subgroup of all $f\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $f(1)=1$ and $\mathcal{C}$ be the subgroup of scalar functions $\epsilon_c(n):=c\epsilon(n)$, where $\epsilon=\text{id}_\mathcal{A}$.  Note that $\mathcal{C}\cap \mathcal{U}=\{\epsilon\}$ Define $(\frac{1}{c}f)(n):=\frac{f(n)}{c}$. If we consider an arbitrary $g\in \mathcal{A}$, then $\frac{1}{f(1)}f\in\mathcal{U}$.  We have $$\left(\frac{1}{g(1)}g\star \epsilon_{g(1)}\right)(n)=\sum_{ab=n}\frac{1}{f(1)}f(a)f(1)\epsilon(b)=(f\star \epsilon)(n)=f(n).$$  Thus we can uniquely factor $f=\frac{1}{f(1)}f\star \epsilon_f(1)$, whence $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{U}\oplus \mathcal{C}$.

Now define $\mathcal{K}\subseteq \mathcal{U}$ to be the subset of (not necessarily multiplicative) functions which vanish on prime powers.  Since $f^{-1}(n)$ is defined in terms of $f(n)$, and since $\mathcal{K}$ is obviously closed under $\star$, it follows immediately that $\mathcal{K}$ is a subgroup of  $\mathcal{U}$.  Again $\mathcal{H}\cap \mathcal{K}=\{\epsilon\}$, where $\mathcal{H}$, as given by OP, is the subgroup of multiplicative functions. For $f\in \mathcal{U}$, define $\Pi_f$ so that $$\Pi_f(p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_s^{e_s})=\prod_{k=1}^r f(p_k^{e_k}).$$  Obviously $\Pi_f\in \mathcal{H}$.  We have that $$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\Pi_f^{-1}\star f \right)(p^{e})&=&\sum_{k=0}^e\Pi_f(p^k)^{-1}f(p^{e-k})\\&=&\sum_{k=0}^e\Pi_f^{-1}(p^k)\Pi_f(p^{e-k})\\&=&(\Pi_f^{-1}\star\Pi_f)(p^e)\\&=&\epsilon(p^e)\\&=&0.\end{eqnarray*}$$
It follows that $\Pi_f^{-1}\star f\in \mathcal{K}$.  Now of course we can write $f=\Pi_f\star\left(\Pi_f^{-1}\star f\right)$, so $f$ uniquely factors into $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$ parts, and we have that $\mathcal{U}=\mathcal{H}\oplus \mathcal{K}$.

So we have obtained that $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{H}\oplus \mathcal{K}\oplus \mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

"However my question is: What is known in the literature about the group structure of G ?"

JOURNAL ARTICLE

Groups of Arithmetical Functions

James E. Delany

Mathematics Magazine

Vol. 78, No. 2 (Apr., 2005), pp. 83-97

Comment: And... I forgot I gave an answer to this question more than 2 years ago. - Hmmm.